# how to make devise use different controller rather than registrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller, registration

I am new to rails and devise. I developed a sample application with rails that has a registration model and registrations controller. So, when I add the devise to my application. It doesn't work!!. I think it is because devise use a controller named registrations and I have another controller named registrations in my application.

My specific problem is: User can not signed up. When I tried to signed up the application redirected to /registrations/user that is not existed and I've got the matching route error.

My RegistrationsController is looks like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController 

    def index
    @registrations = Registration.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
    end

    def show
    @registration = Registration.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    @registration = Registration.new 3.times { @registration.students.build }
    end

    def create

    @registration = Registration.new(params[:registration])

    if params[:file] != nil
      import(params[:file])
    end

    if @registration.save
      redirect_to @registration, :notice => "Successfully created registration."
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
end
```

I'dont know how to solve this problem?? Please tell me how can I use another controller with different name rather than Registrations for the devise.

Comment: I am using devise (2.2.8) on rails (3.1.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, normally when you add the `devise` gem into your project, it works out of the box. You don't need to create any controllers and views. It's all autogenerated for you with `rails generate devise:install`.

So I would recommend just deleting your controller and rely on the Devise one.

However if the default behavior doesn't suit your needs, you can easily overwrite it by putting the following code in your routes:

`devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }`

and defining a controller like this

```
Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def new
#overwriting the default behavior for new here
end

end
```

Note: I made some assumpptions with the above code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I delete my controller and model and create another one, And it is worked.